# Error when using Selenium ChromeDriver on 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 - Status Code -15

Tags: python, linux, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I recently wrote a script utilizing `selenium` and its `chromedriver`. The script is a simple bot program that generates web traffic. I can run this concurrently 24/7 on my Mac, but I recently moved it to a Linux server run by DigitalOcean. Running it there with Ubuntu 14.04, the most recent chromedriver (2.32.498513 in headless mode), and Python 3.6, the bot worked well for about an hour before I hit the following hiccup:

```
Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -15.
```

I wasn't able to find anything on this specific status code online. Perhaps this has something to do with me running it inside of a `screen`?

There was no traceback either so I'm looking for a clue identifying what this error actually means.